# Apply logic/function to "subset" of Spark Dataframe columns

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to adapt the following by passing a list of cols to process as opposed all, except ID. No matter what I do there is some error on cols, Row, etc. With all columns and selecting a subset works fine, but not on a subset in terms of function.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("r1", 1, 1),
   ("r2", 6, 4),
   ("r3", 4, 1),
   ("r4", 1, 2)
   )).toDF("ID", "a", "b")

val ones = df.columns.drop(1).map(x => when(col(x) === 1, 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _)
df.withColumn("ones", ones).show
```

Guidance is sought. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code above works for me. Can you provide a sample of the code that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works for me. I'm not certain what you're trying that is not working. Do you want to check for ones in just some of the rows? In a function?

```
def sumOnes(df: DataFrame, columnNames: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
  val ones = columnNames.map(x => when(col(x) === 1, 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _)
  df.withColumn("ones", ones)
}
```

```
sumOnes(df, Seq("a")).show

+---+---+---+----+
| ID|  a|  b|ones|
+---+---+---+----+
| r1|  1|  1|   1|
| r2|  6|  4|   0|
| r3|  4|  1|   0|
| r4|  1|  2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+
```

```
sumOnes(df, Seq("b")).show

+---+---+---+----+
| ID|  a|  b|ones|
+---+---+---+----+
| r1|  1|  1|   1|
| r2|  6|  4|   0|
| r3|  4|  1|   1|
| r4|  1|  2|   0|
+---+---+---+----+
```

```
sumOnes(df, Seq("a", "b")).show

+---+---+---+----+
| ID|  a|  b|ones|
+---+---+---+----+
| r1|  1|  1|   2|
| r2|  6|  4|   0|
| r3|  4|  1|   1|
| r4|  1|  2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Yes I know it works. But I would like to say only col a.

Comment: The first example in this answer is only col a.

Comment: Looks good,  I was wondering how this would work with withColumn?

Comment: Ie per row that is

Comment: Any thoughts yet on my questions?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Maybe you can edit your question to provide more details about what exactly you're trying to do, and what errors you get? An example of the DataFrame you're hoping to get in the result?

Comment: Pretty easy question, you solution processes the whole dataframe, but if I am already processing the DF, you can see a withColumn, then?? ? I will try again tomorrow